# Can't ping between two directly connected routers (gns3)

Tags: cisco, routing, ping

I was very familiar with this stuff years ago... but I think I may have forgotten some basics. I'm running two images of NX-OS in GNS3. I've configured both as:

```
// Router 1
interface Ethernet2/1
  ip address 192.168.2.101/24
  no shutdown
```

and

```
// Router 2
interface Ethernet2/1
  ip address 192.168.2.102/24
  no shutdown
```

However, I can't ping each other. `sh int status` shows the links as connected:

`Eth2/1        --                 connected routed    full    1000`

Results of the ping though are:

```
N7K-2(config)# ping 192.168.2.101
PING 192.168.2.101 (192.168.2.101): 56 data bytes
2016 Mar  7 03:58:21.792494 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, nh=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=84, id=0c2b, ttl=255
2016 Mar  7 03:58:21.792524 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=21504, id=2b0c, ttl=255
Request 0 timed out
2016 Mar  7 03:58:23.793836 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, nh=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=84, id=0c2c, ttl=255
2016 Mar  7 03:58:23.793999 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=21504, id=2c0c, ttl=255
Request 1 timed out
2016 Mar  7 03:58:25.795381 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, nh=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=84, id=0c2d, ttl=255
2016 Mar  7 03:58:25.795544 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=21504, id=2d0c, ttl=255
Request 2 timed out
2016 Mar  7 03:58:27.797338 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, nh=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=84, id=0c2e, ttl=255
2016 Mar  7 03:58:27.797436 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=21504, id=2e0c, ttl=255
Request 3 timed out
2016 Mar  7 03:58:29.798765 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, nh=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=84, id=0c2f, ttl=255
2016 Mar  7 03:58:29.799104 netstack: [3107] (default) Send packet on Ethernet2/1 (mbuf_prty 7): s=192.168.2.102, d=192.168.2.101, proto=1 (icmp), ip_len=21504, id=2f0c, ttl=255
Request 4 timed out

--- 192.168.2.101 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.00% packet loss
```

This isn't surprising, considering `show cdp neigh` is empty. I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem ended up actually being an error in GNS3:  `Unable to create NIO Ethernet for bridge ethernet0.vnet`

The solution here was to run the following command (as admin): `sc config npf start= auto` and restart the computer.

More details on the bug report: https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-gui/issues/840